# What's a good symbol to show that two devices are connected to one another?

Tags: representation

I'm designing a schematic overview for a client and need to show that a microphone cable is plugged into a video camera. No problem to represent the video camera just as a little box, and the mic with another, even small box. The cable is just represented with a straight line -- but to show that it must be connected is tricky for me, as someone without a background in this sort of stuff.

Suggestions on how to communicate that would be very appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show a small microphone icon, a small camera icon and inbetween a cable. Some Cable that gets bigger at both ends (so its not just a line) and maybe make like surprise/attention lines going from that cable (I hope you mean what I mean) so the user knows that the focus is on that cable inbetween

Comment: Add "Connected" in small type underneath the microphone and camera icon. Further, you could make the icons "active" by making them green vs light grey as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got theese two sketeches:

[image] [image]

Maybe they Inspire you

Answer (score 1):

I would show the connection direction with an arrow like:
[microphone image]-------->[cam image]